# R Kruskal-Wallis with multiple factors

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

I'm looking for help on performing the Kruskal-Wallis test on my set of data for a large number of factors. I can perform the test for a single factor, like AD_1yr:

```
kruskal.test(Shannon ~ AD_1y, data=comm)
```

But I have over 50 factors I want to test, and was hoping there is a code I can enter that will perform the test for all the factors without having to manually perform the test 50 different times.

Comment: N.B. you may want to consider some type of correction calculation since you are making [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `factor` columns, create a `data.frame` with the 'shannon' column and do the `kruskal.test`

```
allfactorcolumns <- sapply(comm, is.factor)
lst <- lapply(comm[allfactorcolumns], function(x) 
    kruskal.test(Shannon~., data= data.frame(x, comm['Shannon'])))
```

If we need to extract the 'p.value', 'df', etc.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) data.frame(Pval= x$p.value, 
                     stat= x$statistic, df= x$parameter)))
```

Comment: @user2988430  Thanks for the feedback.  I forgot a closing `)`

Comment: OK got it to run but it looks like it ran 1 test against all the factors. _data:  Shannon by x
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 79, df = 79, p-value = 0.4788_ I would like it to run 1 test against each factor separately.

Comment: @user2988430  Actually, it is running each factor with 'Shannon' separately.

Comment: Hmm OK. I wanted to get an output where it showed the resulting chi-square, df, and p-value for _each_ factor. Is this possible at all?

Comment: @akun Got an **Error in lapply(lst, function(x) data.frame(Pval = x$p.value, stat = x$statistic,  : 
  object 'lst' not found**

Comment: @user2988430  I created the `lst <- lapply(comm[allfactorcolumns], ...` (if you haven't noticed)

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to create multiple formulas for each model on the same data than to create multiple data frames for each model.